# Arrow spinning on outer radius of circle animation

Tags: javascript

The idea is to have the arrow spin around the circle, on the outer radius. So the arrow has to stick to the outer radius and then follow the outer radius.

It has to start spinning when I click a button 'start' and has to slow down and come to a stop after clicking a button 'stop'

Current HTML

```
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1" width="800px" height="800px">

  <path class="shape" fill="blue" d="
            M 100, 200 
            m 0 -100 
            a 100 100 0 1 0 1 0
            z
            m -1 25    
            a 75 75 0 1 1 -1 0     
            Z" />
</svg>
```

The circle + arrow 
https://codepen.io/tom-truyen/pen/KORgYX

Comment: Please don't link to external resources as the link may go stale in the future. It is better to include relevant content in your question.

Comment: It is in the question the only thing that isn't is the triangle which I have hardcoded to the position using position absolute to give people an idea

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Insert the following below your donut svg:

```
    <script>
        var animate = false;
        var angle = 0;
        function tick() 
        { 
            document.querySelector(".arrow").setAttribute("style", "transform:translate(75px,175px) rotate("+angle+"deg) translate(0px,-112px);");
            angle += 1;
            if (animate) { window.requestAnimationFrame(tick); }
        }
    </script>

    <button onClick="window.animate=true;tick();">start</button>
    <button onClick="window.animate=false;">stop</button>
```

and change the arrow css to:

```
    .arrow {
        height: 50px;
        width: 50px;
        position: absolute;
        transform:translate(75px,175px) translate(0px,-112px);
    }
```

That should do what you asked for.

Comment: Perfect! It's exactly what I needed. seems all so easy now lol, by the way is there a way to speed up the animation?

Comment: Sure, just change `angle += 1;` to something bigger.

Comment: Thank you for helping me. Really appreciate it

Comment: do you by any chance know how I can make the 'stop' make it slow down the arrow first before stopping it?